# SNMPTT and MIB files

Tags: snmp, mib

I have a system setup using SNMPTT to translate incoming traps and put them in a MySQL database. From there, a custom made web application reads out the database and presents the trapt to the user.

The problem is, only basic OID's like linkUp, linkDown and coldRestart are translating currently. The rest is going into the snmptt_unknown log. I figured I'd need the MIB files that correspond to the device I'm using for testen, which is a Cisco Catalyst 2950 switch.

A quick search gave me a large amount of mib files, for all Cisco products.

How do I tell SNMPTT to use these mibs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put to your **snmptt.ini** file line

```
mibs_environment = ALL
```

And restart snmptt. See if that helps.

Comment: How do I restart snmptt herpderp -.- NEVERMIND fixed it.

Comment: You did not mention the operating system you use, or if you installed snmptt from your Linux/BSD distributions package repository or if you compiled if from the source code. A generic way to restart might be `/etc/init.d/snmptt restart`

Comment: Very sorry, I'm running Debian. `service snmptt restart` did it.

Comment: This seems to be working, I can't believe I missed this simple setting.

Comment: Great! :) Have a nice weekend!

Comment: Now that this is done, how do I easily create handlers for all traps? snmpttconvertmib seems to be the way to go, but it only takes one file at a time, and with 2000 mibs that is gonna take ages to input ...

Comment: With a little shell one-liner that should be easy: `for each in /path/to/your/mibs/*; do snmpttconvert --in=/path/to/your/mibs/$each --out=/path/to/snmptt-mib-dir/$each --net_snmp_perl; done`

Comment: Hi, im back. The problem with above solution is that it does not take care of the proper order in which to convert. It will start with the first file, see that it is missing dependencies, and fail. But those dependencies will be fulfilled in other mibs. It fails to see that...